# simplest way to collect all SQL sent out

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

For many reasons I prefer not to disclose (long and boring story), I need to capture the interactions of a complex application with the Database. The application builds on top of Spring/JdbcTemplate and I need to find all the SQL sent out by this application. How can I do that in the simplest possible way?

Creating a pseudo mock implementation of JdbcTemplate does not seem reasonable. First off JdbcTemplate is a class and not an interface. Second it has a large interface that makes it tedious to implement. I am thinking along the lines of mocking `DataSource` and `Connection` to get all the SQL sent out, but maybe there is an easier way to do this?

Comment: If I remember correctly, when setting Spring's loglevel to DEBUG it will write all SQL statements to the logfile

Comment: Correct, but I need this for the purpose of regression testing. I'd prefer not to have my regression testing infrastructure relying on logging output if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of problem is very neatly solved be eg. [P6Spy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p6spy/). There is a [good article](http://swik.net/Spring/Spring%27s+corner/Integrate+P6Spy+with+Spring/vq6) on how to get it working with Spring.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tested it and it works great. Excellent! I'm very happy you saved me from having to reinvent the wheel. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The only way to capture all SQL going out is to be the touch point between your application and the database. This means, decorating the `DataSource`, `Connection`, and all types of `Statement`s from a library implementation that actually handles the JDBC interactions, and note down all the statements being run on your decorated connection from your decorated data source specified in the `SimpleJdbcTemplate` bean definition. It would be challenging from a maintainability perspective to capture this at any other point.

Comment: That's what I thought, makes sense.