# How to get final query from Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I have following code -

```
getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().queryForList("SELECT id FROM emp WHERE age=:age", 
new MapSqlParameterSource("age", 19))
```

How can I get the final query sent to Mysql after parameter replacement? Is there something like -

```
getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate(query, paramSource).gimmeTheFinalQuery()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Incredibly verbose but working solution is -

```
ParsedSql parsedSql = NamedParameterUtils.parseSqlStatement("SELECT id FROM emp WHERE age=:age");
SqlParameterSource source = new MapSqlParameterSource("age", 19);
String finalQuery = new PreparedStatementCreatorFactory(NamedParameterUtils.substituteNamedParameters(parsedSql,
                source), NamedParameterUtils.buildSqlTypeArray(parsedSql, source))
                .newPreparedStatementCreator(NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray(parsedSql, source, null))
                .createPreparedStatement(getConnection()).toString();

finalQuery = finalQuery.substring(finalQuery.indexOf(":") + 1, finalQuery.length());
System.out.println(finalQuery);
```

Output -

> SELECT id FROM emp WHERE age=19

This can be wrapped into a utility class -

```
public class SpringQueryParser {
    Connection con; 
    public SpringQueryParser(Connection con) {
        this.con = con;
    }
    public String getFinalQuery(String query, SqlParameterSource source) throws SQLException {
        ParsedSql parsedSql = NamedParameterUtils.parseSqlStatement(query);
        String finalQuery = new PreparedStatementCreatorFactory(NamedParameterUtils.substituteNamedParameters(parsedSql,
                source), NamedParameterUtils.buildSqlTypeArray(parsedSql, source))
                .newPreparedStatementCreator(NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray(parsedSql, source, null))
                .createPreparedStatement(con).toString();
         return finalQuery.substring(finalQuery.indexOf(":") + 1, finalQuery.length()).trim();
    }
}
```

And then called conveniently as such -

```
new SpringQueryParser(getConnection()).getFinalQuery("SELECT id FROM emp WHERE age=:age",
                new MapSqlParameterSource("age", 19))
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any API like that in Spring, the reason is that the lowest level might not be even available at Spring level. However you may want to take a look at the answer of this other question [Simplest way to collect all SQL sent out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643220/simplest-way-to-collect-all-sql-sent-out). [P6Spy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p6spy/) will do the job nicely by hooking into the `dataSource` bean.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for debugging you can also ask MySQL to log all queries into a log file.

```
> SET GLOBAL general_log_file = '/var/log/mysql_general.log';
> SET GLOBAL general_log = 1;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hibernate to display the SQL statment use the following Hibernate property:

```
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
```

If you use log4j also, then you can set it to show the parameter values that are bound with the statement by setting the following in log4j properties file: `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace`